# Why is the power rule for derivatives not valid here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am stuck on an exercise where I have to figure out the derivative of $y = \frac{\sqrt{20-x^2}}{4}$. I realize that this equation can be rewritten as:

$\frac{1}{4} \times \sqrt{20-x^2}$, so when I factor out the constant $\frac{1}{4}$ on beforehand, this leaves me with $\sqrt{20-x^2}$. This can be rewritten as a power $(20-x^2)^{0.5}$.

My idea was to simply apply the power rule to this equation to find the derivative. This leads to:

$0.5(20-x^2)^{-0.5} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{20-x^2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{20-x^2}}$

However my solution is not valid, and wolfram alpha does something complicated using the chain rule instead. Please help me understand why.

Comment: WolframAlpha didn't use the Chain Rule **instead**, it used the Chain Rule **as well**. Indeed, the Chain Rule is *always* used ... it's just that the final multiplied factor is often just "$1$" (for the derivative of the  variable with respect to itself).

Answer (score 5):

You can employ the power rule, but you forget that in doing so, you're also invoking the chain rule, with kernel $(20-x^2)$. That means you have to multiply your result with the derivative of this expression as well, which is $-2x$. That should give you the answer you're after. Also, don't forget to put back the $\frac{1}{4}$-factor you stripped away at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply also by the derivative of $(20-x^2)$, which is equal to $-2x$. Let's try this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,chain rule has to be applied because there are two functions here...a function of a function.

To derive that you find the derivative of the inner function multiplied by the derivative of the outer function. Using methods from Pure Mathematics 1 by Hugh Neil--->

Let $u=20-x^2$ right?
So the function is now $y=u^{0.5}$ 
So you can differentiate that which is in terms of variable u so it is $\frac{dy}{du}$.
since $u=20-x^2$ you differentiate that too to get $\frac{du}{dx}$
.But your question is asking for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ which can be arrived at by multiplying the two hence--->
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx}$. If you write that out notice that the $du$ cancels out the other and you will remain with $\frac{dy}{dx}$.
Write it on paper and substitute, my formatting is not good need to get all my HTML tags together. Tell us if this explanation is of use to you.